# What types of wild foods are protected from foraging in the Swedish Lapland forests, and how is the status decided?

Tags: food, foraging, forests, conservation, sweden

There's a question on the site seeking information about foraging food in Sweden. One of the answers says any wild food in the forests of Swedish Lapland can be foraged and removed except "protected" food.

What types of edible wild things in that region are protected? Which governing bodies or organizations decide the criteria necessary to receive protected status?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Protected species in sweden are listed in English here: [Protected Species in Sweden](http://www.swedishepa.se/Enjoying-nature/Animal-and-plants/Protected-species/).

Since information is subject to change I will not copy the information into this answer.

Apart from that, hunting and fishing is regulated. Naturally, anything grown commercially is off limits too, since that is the property of the land owner.

Note that National Parks/nature reserves have special rules, and You'll need to check the specifics for the actual area.

Comment: You surely mean *crops in the intentionally-planted field areas*, not wild or ["volunteer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volunteer_(botany)) plants in areas not intended to be farmed.

Comment: Actually I was intentionally vague, since wild plants MIGHT be considered as “crops” if the land owner put enough effort in their care and made a court case.